# Accept lvalue ref or rvalue ref

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

I want to write some functions that take an `Object` as one of their arguments, whether by lvalue or rvalue ref doesn't matter - but definitely not by value and definitely only an `Object`. It seems like I have two options for this:

```
void foo(Object& o) {
    // stuff
}

void foo(Object&& o) { foo(o); } // this is fine for my use-case
```

Or using universal references:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
using decays_to = typename std::is_same<std::decay_t<T>, U>::type;

template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<decays_to<T, Object>::value>
foo(T&& o) 
{
    // same stuff as before
}
```

But the first option involves writing twice as many functions as I need, and the second option involves writing a bunch of template stuff which is seems like overkill to me (I kind of read that as accept *anything* for `o` - oh just kidding, really just an `Object`).

Is there a better way to solve this or am I just pretty much stuck with whichever one of these I feel less meh about?

Comment: Would `void foo(Object const& o)` suffice? It will accept both r-value and l-value, but it is `const`.

Comment: @Niall wow. it totally would. sometimes, I apparently massively overthink things.

Comment: `std::remove_const_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>` would be a better choice than `std::decay_t<T>` since [`decay_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) has the side effect of performing function-to-pointer and array-to-pointer conversions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The typical way to accept both lvalues and rvalues is to make a function that takes a const reference. That means you can't call non-const functions on the object, but if you want to pass rvalues such as temporaries, then calling non-const functions wouldn't necesarily make much sense anyway.

Answer (score 6):

There is a difference between your two implementations.  The first will admit anything convertible to `Object`, `Object&&` or `Object&`.  The second will only admit `Object` and things that inherit from it in rvalue or lvalue form (and reject `const Object`s, much like the first).

We can add a helper object:

```
template<class T>
struct l_or_r_value {
  T& t;
  l_or_r_value( T&& t_ ):t(t_) {}
  l_or_r_value( T& t_ ):t(t_) {}
  operator T&(){ return t; }
  T* operator->(){ return &t; }
  T& operator*(){ return t; }
  T& get(){ return t; }
};
```

then we can write:

```
void foo(l_or_r_value<Object> o)
```

and we get behavior that is very close to your second solution, without the template mumbo jumbo at point of call.  You do have to access `*o` and `o->` or do a `Object& o = o_;` to get at the raw reference.

It is not like the first solution, because C++ does not chain two user-defined conversions.

The concepts proposal would add the ability to say "I take anything here, so long as it is an `Object`" with a more terse syntax.

Another approach would be to just take `Object&`, and use:

```
tepmlate<class T>
T& lvalue( T&& t) { return t; }
```

to convert rvalues to lvalues when you need to (you could also call it `unmove` to be cute)

Comment: I really like this answer - and will probably use `l_or_r_value` somewhere - but I'm accepting the other one just because it's more straightforward for my use-case.

Comment: @Barry ah!  Sorry, I figured you actually wanted to modify the value in the function, and rejecting `const` objects was on purpose.

Comment: Nope, was rejecting them based solely on a problem that exists between the keyboard and the chair.